# find elements which id contains two substrings

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, contains

I have an HTML table and I need to change the CSS style to all de `<td>` whose `"id"` contains the substring `"_A_189"` and the substring `"_B_V_852"` using jquery. The substrings could be in any position of the string.

I use this, but it doen't work:

```
$('id:contains("_A_189"):contains("_B_V_852")').css(style);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets to select by attribute:

```
$("[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852']").css(style);
```

And in case of this question it's even better to narrow it down to only td elements:

```
$("td[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852']").css(style);
```

"[id*='str']" means "find an element where attribute 'id' contains string 'str' anywhere".

More info at jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

EDIT:
This selector is available in css, not only in jQuery, so if '_A_189' and '_B_V_852' parts are static, you should consider adding it to your stylesheet instead of using scripts. For instance:

```
table td[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852'] {
    /* your styles */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the the easiest way.

Comment: Just to note, the code above will run on every id element on the dom - the op asked for only td elements, and it will run quicker if you specify only to check the ids of td elements:

      $( "td[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852']").css(style);

Comment: Yes, that's true. Also if the call is meant to edit cells of just one table it'd be even better to include it in jQuery/css selector: $("table#my_table_id td[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852']").css(style);

Comment: It's maybe worth showing that you could select these elements (with the same selector) directly in CSS, rather than going through jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If the two strings can be "*in any position*", then the only way to select them, realistically, is with `filter()`:

```
// finds all <td> elements with an 'id', filters that collection:
$('td[id]').filter(function () {
    // retains only those elements for which the assessment returns true
    // (the strings of both '_A_189' AND
    // the string '_B_V_852' must be found within the id property:
    return this.id.indexOf('_A_189') > -1 && this.id.indexOf('_B_V_852') > -1;
// the found/retained elements remain in the chain, passed to
// the css() method:
}).css(/* style */);
```

Your original attempt:

```
$('id:contains("_A_189"):contains("_B_V_852")').css(style);
```

Didn't work, because the `:contains()` selector looks at the text-content of an element to find the string(s) you're searching for, not the attributes/properties of the elements.

Also, because there's no `.`, `#`, `:` or other character to indicate otherwise, this jQuery is looking for an element-type of `<id>`, rather than looking at all elements for an `id` *attribute*, whose text contains the strings supplied to the `:contains()` selector.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).
  - [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

the correct css selector for contains is [attribute*=substring], so with jquery:

$('[id*="_A_189"][id*="_B_V_852"]').css(style);

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite simply:

```
$( "td[id*='_A_189'][id*='_B_V_852']").css(style);
```